# Count length of JSON object for particular attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a variable named as "data" with thousand of values in format like:

```
 var data = "[{"latitude":"12.97345167","longitude":"77.62284667"},{"latitude":"12.97333167","longitude":"77.62262833"},{"latitude":"12.972285","longitude":"77.619655"},{"latitude":"12.97223","longitude":"77.61964333"},{"latitude":"12.97182333","longitude":"77.619525"},{"latitude":"12.97205667","longitude":"77.619555"}]"
```

after performing JSON.parse() on this object i want to get the count of all values in "latitude".

Comment: you mean the number of latitude in it or the sum of all values of latitude?

Comment: There's a `latitude` in every Object in the Array. So why wouldn't you just get the length of the Array?

Comment: yes thanks it served the purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `data` is an array with each entry having a latitude and longitude. Wouldn't `data.length` do the trick?

```
var data = JSON.parse("your long JSON");
console.log(data.length); //number of entries
```